# Dynamic table using FPDF and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, fpdf

I am making a Invoice Kind of System where we can select the number of heading and fields(no. of rows) using FPDF and PHP. After that, I can pass the heading name and field values in input field of HTML.

The problem I'm facing is all the field values are coming in one single line of one cell after other in next line. I want to show the field column wise. For example, if I have two columns with heading Work and Amount.

In work column I want to show Work 1,WorK 2,..Work 4,etc. and in amount column I want to show Amount 1,Amount 2,..Amount 4,etc.

Attaching all references making it easier to understand the problem.

[image]

This is the code of my HTML:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Invoice Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-container w-50 m-auto">
    <section class="my-5">
        <div class="py-5">
            <h1 class="text-center"><img src="Logo.png" alt="Logo"></h1>
                </div>
        <div class="w-50 m-auto">
                <form action="invoice.php" method="post" class="py-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Date</label>
                    <input type="date" name="date" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" required value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>"><br>
                    <label>How many Headings do you want?</label>
                    <select name="heading-list" id="heading-list">
                        <option></option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>How many fields do you want?</label>
                    <select name="fields-list" id="fields-list">
                        <option></option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                        <option>6</option>
                        <option>7</option>
                        <option>8</option>
                        <option>9</option>
                        <option>10</option>
                    </select>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="headingfieldbtn" id="headingfieldbtn" onclick="addfields()">Submit for Heading and Fields</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" name="resetbtn">Reset</button>
                    <div id="dynamic_field" class="form-group"></div>
                    <button type="submit" name="submitbtn" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form> 
                

</div>
<script>
function addfields(){
headings=document.querySelector('#heading-list'); 
headingsvalue=headings.value;
fields=document.querySelector('#fields-list'); 
fieldsvalue=fields.value;
    for (i=1; i<=headingsvalue ; i++) {
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<input type="text" name="heading[]" placeholder="Heading" class="form-control"/>');}
    for (j=1; j<=fieldsvalue; j++) { 
    for (k=1; k<=headingsvalue ; k++) { 
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<input type="text" name="field[]" placeholder="Field" class="form-control"/>');
    }}
    $("#headingfieldbtn").prop('disabled',true);
    $("#heading-list").prop('disabled',true);
    $("#fields-list").prop('disabled',true);

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my PHP code made using FPDF Library:-

```
if(isset($submitbtn)){
    $pdf= new FPDF();

    $pdf->AddPage('P','A4');
    $pdf->AddFont('Montserrat-Regular','','Montserrat-Regular.php');
    $pdf->AddFont('Montserrat-Bold','','Montserrat-Bold.php');  
    $pdf->SetFont("Montserrat-Bold",'',15);
    $pdf->Image('Header.png',0,0);
    $pdf->SetY(-200);
    $pdf->Cell(50,10,"DESIGN PROPORSAL",0,1);
    $pdf->SetFont("Montserrat-Regular",'',15);
    $pdf->MultiCell(0,8,"This invoice for design services is prepared for . It is for the emailers. This quotation will remain closed.",0,'J');
    $pdf->SetFont("Montserrat-Bold",'',12);
    $pdf->Cell(15,10,"Date:",0,0);
    $pdf->Cell(50,10,$date,0,1);
    if(!empty($heading)){
    foreach ($heading as $heading) {
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,$heading,1,0);}
    $pdf->Ln();
    foreach ($field as $field){ 
    $pdf->MultiCell(40,10,$field,1);}   
    }
    ob_end_clean();
    $pdf->output();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will always have a field value to go along with a heading you need to move the output of the field values into the same loop as the headings.

You also need to change the names of the variables as you go through the `foreach` otherwise you will destroy the original the first time through.

```
if(!empty($heading)){
    foreach ($heading as $point => $head) {
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,$head,1,0);
        $pdf->MultiCell(40,10,$field[$point],1);
        $pdf->Ln();
        }  // end of foreach
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me once again. Im confused. Do i need to use only one foreach loop?

Comment: Have you tried what I posted in my answer? Yes, you should only need 1 foreach loop ....  you will want to make sure that you get a value for each header either by checking that with JS or in PHP.

Comment: I tried your method, though I'm getting all headings but not all fields. Also I need to show headers horizontally, it's showing me veritcally.

Comment: For example, if I want two fields and two headers so I will have total 6 cells(2 for headers and 4 for fields)  so my output should look like this:- ABC DEF                                                                              
                                                1   2                                                                                                        
                                                3   4